# Trying to write vhdl code for a specific entity-architecture

Tags: vhdl

I have to write the VHDL code for the following entity-architecture design:

develop a "machine" with the following signals:
- clock input (100Mhz)
- 4 input lines (1-bit) called: REQ0...REQ3
- 4 output lines (1-bit) called: GRANT0...GRANT3
- a reset signal (input)

The machine checks the input lines on every clock rising edge.
If one input line is "high" (bit 1), it sets an high value on the corresponding GRANT line. The GRANTi line turns low when, on the rising edge of the clock, the corresponding REQi line turns low, or after 8 (module 8 counter) clock cycles. 
If more than ones REQi lines are high at the same time, only one GRANTi line can turns high (whatever line GRANTi you want), but can't turns high the line just lowered.

I hope the text is clear. I was not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In general, homework questions enjoy/suffer a special treatment. First you have to show some effort and demonstrate the work you have done so far, which you have not I am afraid. Also for homework/assignments  we don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic
questions. Otherwise, we would be doing you a
disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time.
See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036)

Comment: Thanks @Oldfart. You are right. The main problem here, for me, was to figure out the last part of the text. The first part was easy to write the vhdl code (unfortunately I only have a picture of the code written during the exam), but I just need an hint to understand the last part when REQi lines are high simultaneously.

Comment: If you get multiple requests, at the exact same time or "stacked" as another one was still being granted, you have to pick only one to grant, and let the other(s) request(s) wait some more time.